# Matrix similarity

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> $A$ and $B$ are two square matrices 3x3. You know that the
>   characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p_A = -t^3 - t^2 + 6t$, and the
>   eigenvalues of $B$ are $\beta_1 = 0$, $\beta_2 = 2$ and $\beta_3 = -3$.
>
> Can you determine if the matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar or not? Justify your answer.

My answer is the following: I can easily found (by substitution) that the eigenvalues of $A$ are the same of $B$, so both $A$ and $B$ are similar to the following diagonal matrix:

$$\Delta = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -3\end{pmatrix}$$

From this I can say that $A$ and $B$ are similar.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Yes. similar matrices have the same Jordan normal form, and conversely.

Comment: @Bernard So, in general, is the following statement true?

$A$ has the same eigenvalues of $B$ $\implies$ $A$ and $B$ are similar

Comment: Not at all. There may be different Jordan normal forms corresponding to the same eigenvalues. When the matrix has distinct $n$ distinct eigenvalues ($n$ dimension of the matrix), its Jordan normal form is  diagonal, hence all matrices with the same  $\color{red}{n}$  *distinct* eigenvalues are similar. But that is an exception.

Comment: @ᴜsᴇʀ No. Although the implication does go the other way.

Comment: @Dave Do you refer to the original question or to my previous comment?

Comment: @ᴜsᴇʀ To the comment.

Comment: @Bernard I've not understand very well. Do you mean that: $A, B \in \mathscr M_\mathbb R(n)$, $A$ has the same eigenvalues of $B$ ⟹ $A$ and $B$ are similar ?

Comment: If there are $n$ *distinct* eigenvalues.

Comment: @Bernard So, for example if $A, B \in \mathscr M_\mathbb R(3)$ and the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are $\alpha_1 = \beta_1 = 1$, $\alpha_2 = \beta_2 = 1$, $\alpha_3 = \beta_3 = 2$, I can't say that $A$ and $B$ are similar. Instead if $\alpha_1 = \beta_1 = 1$, $\alpha_2 = \beta_2 = 2$, $\alpha_3 = \beta_3 = 3$, $A$ and $B$ are similar. Right?

Comment: In the second case, yes. In the first case, they may or may not be similar, that depends on finer invariants, called the similarity invariants. In the present simple case, it depends on the dimension of the eigenspace $E_1$ associated to the eigenvalue $1$: if it has dimension $2$, it is diagonalisable: if it has dimension $2$, its Jordan normal form has a $1$ above the diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be direct and precise:

$$p_A(t)=-t^3-t^2+6t=-t(t^2+t-6)=-t(t+3)(t-2)$$

and thus both $\;A,B\;$ have the same three distinct eigenvalues $\;-3,\,0,\,2\;$, so both matrices are diagonalizable and, thus, they **have the same Jordan form** $\;\iff\;$ **they are similar**.

For example, the following two matrices are *not* similar, even though they have the same eigenvalues:  one and two.

$$\begin{pmatrix}2&1&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\ncong\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: In your example: are the eigenvalues $1$ and $2$ (and not $0$ and $1$) or did I missed something?

Comment: The eigenvalues, as seen in the Jordan forms above, are $\;2\;$, with multiplicity two, and $\;1\;$ with multiplicity 1, *in both cases*.

Comment: I mean: `For example, the following two matrices are not similar, even though they have the same eigenvalues: zero and one.` I don't understand what are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @ᴜsᴇʀ Stupid typo of me. Sorry, editing that.